# Android HTTp connections

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

The android developer blog [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html) explains the 2 different methods to make http connections in android. It says the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) should be used for newer apps.

What I want to know is what are the bugs in [DefaulHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) when used in android 2.3(Gingerbread) and above?

#### EDIT

Removed second part of the question. I want to know mainly about the bugs with the DefaultHttpConnection in 2.3 and above because I have a very small use case (POST requests sending and receiving JSON formatted strings) and if there is no problem in this use case I don't want to bloat my code.

Comment: If it's a small use case, why don't you simply rewrite it using the newer and supported api?

Comment: I am doing that. I also want to know if any bugs exist in the current implementation which used DefaultHttpClient. If there aren't any for my use case then this is low priority otherwise very high priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Build.VERSION to find out which version of Android your application is running on and use that to decide which way to go.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Comment: Any idea what the bugs are with the DefaultHttpConnection with 2.3 and above?

Comment: it is not DefaultHttpConnection but it is DefaultHttpClient, this class is not being maintained / updated in Google's repository and everyone should use HttpURLConnection which is also found in standard Java. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: That is the same link as the one from the question. I saw it but wanted details on the bugs in the DefaultHttpClient in 2.3 and above. If none of the bugs affect my use case then this is already implemented for me.

Comment: Well not being maintained would be bad enough, and because its just a few lines of code, I would have gone that way but anyways here are some links that showed up from a simple google query: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/LCkH9mMwwSQ  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225638/android-defaulthttpclient-execute-not-returns-when-using-mobile-network  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835260/android-httpclient-digest-authentication-authorization-header-nc-hard-coded

Comment: and finally the scary one: http://android.bigresource.com/Android-Can-039-t-download-with-HttpClient-with-a-different-server-port-Av3nzgHF9.html